# Get mean of two ros::Time stamps

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given two `ros::Time` instances `t1` and `t2`. What is the easiest, clearest way to compute the mean them, that is the time that is in the middle between `t1` and `t2`?

The obvious solution `(t1 + t2) / 2` does unfortunately not work, as `+` is undefined for two `ros::Time` instances.

My second idea, `t1 + (t2 - t1) / 2` does still not work. The subtraction and addition work, but it will fail on the division.

Of course, I could just convert the time stamps to seconds to do the calculation, but I wonder if there is a nicer way, using `ros::Time`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205487/get-mean-of-two-ros::time-stamps/) by [luator](https://answers.ros.org/users/21035/luator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2015-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to work:

```
ros::Time start;
ros::Time end;

ros::Time mid = start + (end - start) *0.5;
```

You can only add a Duration to a time (and subtracting one Time from another gives a Duration).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luator](https://answers.ros.org/users/21035/luator/) on 2015-03-27**:
Strange, that multiplication is implemented but division is not... Thanks a lot.